# Is there a way to stop go test in VS code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, testing

I have super long running test and I have to manually make it stop in VS code. (I am not talking about tests triggered in terminal.)

Currently, I just close my VS code to stop it.

This github says `This feature is out in the latest update to the Go extension (0.6.82) thanks to @tylerb!`

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1047

But I cannot find the button to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of the Go extension installed.Once that's sorted, you should see a stop button in the status bar at the bottom of the window when a test is running. It's a square icon with a stop symbol inside.

Have you tried checking the command palette? You can open it with `Ctrl+Shift+P` (or `Cmd+Shift+P` on macOS) and then type "stop" or "cancel" to see if there's a command related to stopping tests.